# Why is my owner-drawn combobox shown empty?

Tags: user-interface, winapi, combobox, wtl, ownerdrawn

I'm subclassing a WTL combobox and I'm owner-drawing the items of the combobox. The control has the attributes `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_HASSTRINGS | CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` and I'm using the mix-in class COwnerDraw to implement DrawItem() and MeasureItem(). When the drop down list is down, the items are drawn correctly. However when the drop down list is up, the combobox control is empty and the item isn't drawn. What am I doing wrong?

The WTL class looks like this:

```
class CMyComboBox :
   public CWindowImpl<CMyComboBox, CComboBox>,
   public COwnerDraw<CMyComboBox>
{
public:
   BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX(CMyComboBox)
      CHAIN_MSG_MAP(COwnerDraw<CMyComboBox>)
      CHAIN_MSG_MAP_ALT(COwnerDraw<CMyComboBox>, 1)
   END_MSG_MAP()

   void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS)
   {
      CDCHandle dc = lpDIS->hDC;
      dc.FillSolidRect(&lpDIS->rcItem, lpDIS->itemID == 0 ?
         RGB(255,0,0) : RGB(0,255,0));
   }

   void MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct)
   {
      lpMeasureItemStruct->itemWidth = 12;
      lpMeasureItemStruct->itemHeight = 12;
   }
};
```

The class is used on a dialog and is subclassed like this:

```
   m_cbMy.SubclassWindow(GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO1));
   m_cbMy.AddString(_T("Item 1"));
   m_cbMy.AddString(_T("Item 2"));
```

Changing the control attributes to `CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` doesn't change anything.

---

Edit:
Thanks to the help of najmeddine I figured out that I have to handle WM_PAINT to draw the actual combobox, and not only the items in the drop-down list. Unfortunately now I have to also draw the combobox control all by myself. Is there a way to let the GDI draw the border and drop arrow so that I only have to draw the "insides" of the control?

Comment: I am trying to do the same, with mixed success (currently using DrawThemeBackground). Could you find a reliable solution to draw the dropdown arrow?

Comment: I didn't implement the suggestion from David M, only handled the WM_PAINT message to draw the combobox myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To draw the combobox control you should use the theme APIs in your WM_PAINT handler (in XP+ - you don't say what Windows versions you need to support.)  Specifically, use [`DrawThemeBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289%28VS.85%29.aspx), and pass in one of the [`CB_` values for iPartId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You will also need to use the [buffered paint APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773257%28VS.85%29.aspx) to handle transitions on Vista, which can complicate your paint handler - this and other drawing problems when custom painting a combobox control are [explained here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29400336/re-dropdown-list-with-c.aspx) in a fair amount of detail.  I'd suggest using that forum thread as your main reference implementing this.

Comment: For future reference: DrawThemeBackground offers various parts to draw, among others `CP_READONLY` (from what I have seen, corresponing to `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`). Unfortunately, `CP_READONLY` does not incorporate the dropdown arrow. But there is still `CP_DROPDOWNBUTTONRIGHT`, but this, in turn is not only the arrow, but contains a border, so it can not be used with `CP_READONLY` right away (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199120/draw-themed-combobox-on-windows?noredirect=1#comment81352380_47199120).

Answer (score 0):

On DrawItem you filling a rect with some color. But where is DrawText or something like it?

[Example of custom DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc9hahtd%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: That's my custom drawing, filling the rect. No need to output text.

Answer (score 0):

To draw the comboBox control (not the list), you should also handle the `WM_PAINT` message and do your painting there.
the `DrawItem` event only paints the drop list and it's items.