# Draw themed combobox on windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, combobox, themes, visual-styles

I try to emulate the look of a themed noneditable combobox (`CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`) using [`DrawThemeBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb773306(v=vs.85).aspx). I supply the part [`CP_READONLY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb773210(v=vs.85).aspx), which apparently draws the background of a themed combobox:

```
DrawThemeBackground(theme, dc, CP_READONLY, CBRO_NORMAL, &rectangle, nullptr);
```

However, it does not contain the dropdown arrow. So, I tried to paint the arrow myself the following way:

```
rectangle.left = rectangle.right - 20;
DrawThemeBackground(theme, dc, CP_DROPDOWNBUTTONRIGHT, CBXSR_NORMAL, &rectangle, nullptr);
```

But the above draws the arrow *centered* within the rectangle on a combobox background *including the border*, so I cannot use this without having a border within the combobox (which itself already has a border). I used [theme-explorer](https://github.com/mity/theme-explorer) to verify that the arrow is always on a background with borders.

In essence, my question is: **How can I draw the background *and* the arrow at the appropriate position to emulate the look of a plain windows combobox?**

What I have found out so far:

- I can specify a clipping rectangle to clip away the aforementioned borders. But this poses the question of determining the exact position rectangle and the clipping rectangle: It seems that I can use [`GetThemeMargins`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb759755(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine the margins, but that does not tell me how large the arrow is as a whole.
- [`GetThemeBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb773388(v=vs.85).aspx) might be useful in determining the exact size of the arrow, but as I read [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620045/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-Visual-Styles) and confirmed on my machine, using it with `TMT_GLYPHDIBDATA` does not work as advertised, and I would like to go without any workarounds, if possible.

Comment: The smart way of asking this question is to post the code you tried instead of asking for the manual.  Consider the [.NET Framework code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBoxRenderer.cs,28f45b7a03475ba8), it doesn't try to draw it all in one whack either.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the hint, I updated my question accordingly. Regarding the .NET code, as far as I can tell, it goes down exactly to my second call (which results in an additional border), so I suspect this routine is only used for editable comboboxes where a border around the drop-down button makes sense.